# Magento Observer not being called on order payment pay

Tags: xml, events, magento, observer-pattern

UPDATED 05/08/2011 *******

I am new to magento and trying to create an observer that will be triggered upon the payment of an order. For now the observer just sends an email however i will be extending upon this in the future, however i need to get the code working first.

I am using Magento 1.5.1.0 and having looked at the event hooks cheatsheat @ http://www.nicksays.co.uk/magento_events_cheat_sheet/ i can see that the event i want to hook onto is

> 'sales_order_payment_pay'

that is dispatched from

```
'app/code/local/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Payment.php'.
```

as i have overwitten the file in the core folder

After reading numerous articles i understand i need to create 3 files which are as follows

1. app/etc/modules/PackageName_ModuleName.xml - > contains the xml file stating where the module can be found
2. app/code/local/PackageName/ModuleName/etc/config.xml -> which
       attaches the observer to the dispatched 'sales_order_payment_pay' event
3. app/code/local/PackageName/ModuleName/Model/Observer.php -> consists of a class which contains a method that is called by config.xml when the 'sales_order_payment_pay event is fired.

Here are the files i have created and the directory's the files live in, the code will be extended to do more than send an email when 'sales_order_payment_pay' is triggered, i am just debugging at the minuite.

My code is as follows, No email is being recived on payment of orders

app/etc/modules/Juno_Sales.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Juno_Finalise>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Juno_Finalise>
    </modules>
</config>
```

app/code/local/Juno/Sales/etc/config.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Juno_Sales>
                <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Juno_Sales>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <junofinalise>
                <class>Juno_Sales_Model</class>
            </junofinalise>
        </models>          
        <events>
                <sales_order_payment_pay>
                <observers>
                        <juno_sales_order_observer>
                                <type>singleton</type>
                                <class>junofinalise/order_observer</class>
                                <method>finaliseJunoOrder</method>
                        </juno_sales_order_observer>
                </observers>
                </sales_order_payment_pay>     
        </events>
     </global>
</config>
```

app/code/local/Juno/Sales/Model/Order/Observer.php

```
 <?php
Mage::log(__FILE__);

class Juno_Finalise_Model_Order_Observer
{

    public function finaliseJunoOrder($event)
    {
         mail('ian.cassidy1404@gmail.com','call_juno_api','now call juno api');

        /*
                Sale has now been processed and is paid for, function needs modifying to call juno api 
        */


    }

}

?>
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Many thanks

Ian

Answer (score 4):

Your class `Juno_Finalise_Model_Observer` should be `Juno_Finalise_Model_Order_Observer`.

Comment: hello there, i have tried this but still no luck, do you think it is because the observer needs to be in the same directory as the file that dispatches the event i.e

Comment: The observer definitely does NOT need to be in the same directory.

Comment: Let's make sure that your module is correctly being loaded. In the admin go to _System > Cache Management_ and turn all caches off for as long as you are debugging. Install [this module](http://alanstorm.com/magento_list_module) and check yours is listed. Also go to _System > Configuration > Developer_ and turn on logging then at the top of the observer file put `Mage::log(__FILE__);` - watch the var/log/system.log file to see if that file is ever read.

Comment: sorry about that, 

1. i have turned all caches off
2. the module is installed and showing
3. nothing is being written to the core file so i assume the observer is never being called

i have updated my code above to how it looks now, i did notice that the dispatch event is comming from app/code/local/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Payment.php which overrides the core file. Could this be why it is not working? 

thanks for all your help

Comment: I see you've changed some instances of "Finalise" to "Sales". Remember to do this everywhere including in class names (which must match their path names) and the module name in both XML files. I've never known an event to fail simply because it is being dispatched from a `local` directory, overrides should have no effect at all. Have you tried placing a breakpoint or another `Mage::log` at the point where you think an event originates?

Comment: Hello again clockworkgeek, thanks for all your help i have got it working now! i found using the Mage::log very useful in debugging.

Comment: You're most welcome. Here at SO when someone has given you the correct answer you should tick the checkmark next to that answer so others can see what the resolution was. Also we both get points for it ;)